# script and formula for timestamp when a check mark is filled

Tags: checkbox, timestamp, defaultifempty

I saw this response (below) from a poster responding to a request for an automatic timestamp when a cell is filled out.  I've added this script as a new project in Google Sheets.  My question is, what is the formula to use in the cell where I want the timestamp??

Henrique G. Abreu said:  "Just to help you get started ... "automatic timestamp when a cell is filled out ...

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { //checks the column
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
  if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
    nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```

This code does what I understood from yours, which is: if something is edited on column D and column E is empty, add the current date to E."

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you are using.

Comment: [At least] the title needs clarifying what the scenario is.

Comment: If the response in reference is on another stachexchange question, this question here should instead be a comment on that other question.  If not on stackexchange, at least link here to wherever that reference is.

Comment: Grammar in last 2 sentences is confusing:  Are you directing those sentence to someone specific (emphasis "yours"), or are you describing your own understanding of the code in general?